# Full adder using DEC 2/4

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, decoder

I want to design a full adder of one bit numbers using 2/4 Decoders and NOR gates.

I have the truth table: [image]

Now, what's confusing me are the inputs and outputs. The inputs for one DEC would be A and B, right? What do I do with Cin and Cout? Everything goes into the NOR gate and there's S, but how to get there?

Comment: Just build some 3:8 decoder out of multiple 2:4 decoders

Comment: Then I would use 2 decoders, the inputs would be A and B and control input Cin... The rest is just like 3/8 decoder, with numbers  0 to 7 going into the gates and making S and Cout. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you understand how two half-adders can be combined to make a full adder?

Comment: @DaveTweed No, not really.

Comment: See my answer below. U1 and NOR1 constitute a half-adder, and so do U2 and NOR2 (albeit with a slight twist). Note that I'm assuming that this is a homework problem, which is why I'm not giving a complete answer here. If you want more explicit help, you're going to have to be more clear about where this problem came from and what you DO understand about it -- and what you understand about logic design in general.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you for helping. I'll work out the rest on my own. It's not homework though, but is related to college. For this problem I had the truth tables and didn't know what to do next, since I have little experience and understanding of 2/4 decoders. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you are constrained to use decoders and NOR gates, the logic is a whole lot simpler if you redefine the carry inputs and outputs to be active-low instead of active-high. I'll present a solution based on this, and maybe it will provide some insight to your original problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6fttD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Actually, it only requires one additional gate to make them active-high, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Full adder using 2 to 4 decoders.

Comment: Hi @Ashok, welcome to EE.SE. Can you please explain how is this answer different from the previous answer by @DaveTweed?